# Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function, using a third party library (Using Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I'm trying to develop an application using Qt and library to connect to a software server that controls an external USB device.

I created a new empty project and added a button and a textview.

I've also added these lines to the .pro file

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/iview/lib/ -liViewXAPI
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/iview/lib/ -liViewXAPId

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/iview/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/iview/include
```

The paths mentioned above have both the .dlls and the .lib files. The machine in which I'm programming was delivered with the device to the Im sure that it is meant to work under Windows 7 x32. I've only written the following three lines of code:

```
ui->pteLog->appendPlainText("Establishing connection to server ....");    
int result = iV_ConnectLocal();
ui->pteLog->appendPlainText("Result for connection was: " + QString::number(result));
```

When I try to run my application, I get the following output in the Application Output Window:

```
Attempting to open InpOut driver...
Successfully opened inpout32 driver
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Error - RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073741823. Will try to launch the process directly
Closing InpOut driver...
```

The program crashes.

Is there any chance that this is happening simply because I've misconfigured Qt for use with the external library?

I'm using Qt 5.8.0 With MinGW 5.3.0 if that is of any use.

As requested, more information is given on the program and API:
The Function iV_Connnecthttps://www.smivision.com/). That server controls a device from the company connected to the PC through a USB Port. So to control de device you need to establish a connection to the server using a provided API. All of this works as the Laptop comes with the device and all the software installed (proprietary software provided by the company) which obviously connects to the device and works just fine.  However, They also provide an API (called [iViewXApi](http://tsgdoc.socsci.ru.nl/images/c/cb/IView_X_SDK_Manual.pdf)) so that you can make your custom software. This is what I want to do. So I did a Qt Program and the first step is to simply connect to the server. The line iV_ConnectLocal does exactly that.

Comment: What is the function signature of `pteLog->appendPlainText()`?

Comment: I don't understand the question (What is the function signature?). But. If I comment the iV_Connect line, this works and I've used the other lines a lot. I don't think those are the problem.

Comment: What is the signature of the function? For example, it might be `void appendPlainText(const char*);`

Comment: You haven't give crucial information about what we need: what does the function expect so I can find out how it's misbehaving.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the API documentation. Is there any chance you can use the Python ctypes module and try to run the following example: "from ctypes import *; iViewXAPI = windll.LoadLibrary("iViewXAPI.dll"); iViewXAPI.iV_Connect(c_char_p('127.0.0.1'), c_int(4444), c_char_p('127.0.0.1'), c_int(5555))"?

Comment: I never did use the LoadLibrary command as I did not know that it was from the windows.h library. When I get home I'm going to try to use that on the C program. If it doesn't work, my next step is going to by python. Unfortunately that documentation is very updated (only thing I could find already online). But I do have the up to date pdf installed in the Laptop. I'll report back with what happened.